How to set configuration location on installation?
I'd like to use the configuration location above the webroot, $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/sync'; in settings.php, as recommended by the documentation here, Changing the storage location of the sync directory.
Is there a way to set this during installation with composer.json?

Yes. Configure scaffold to modify default.settings.php by one of the documented methods.

The pre-drupal-scaffold-cmd to patch default.settings.php in order to keep up with Drupal core changes?

Provide context for links Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
